# Getting Lumen to talk to Codeception

Tags: php, codeception, lumen

A colleague of mine is having an issue trying to get a Lumen module working for Codeception.  He has added some notes here:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/codeception-lumen-module

He is trying to create a Lumen module for Codeception based on the Laravel5 module, without success.  Laravel implements an HttpKernel but Lumen does not, it appears that the  http kernel translates Laravel's requests for codeception tests, so attempting to run the tests without initializing the http kernel doesn't work.

It may be the case that we need to use the Symfony Http\Kernel rather than the Laravel one, in which case how do we initialize that kernel module from codeception?

Has anyone else done any work towards getting Codeception tests running with Lumen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked that current project and I believe I may have a working copy of this package.

https://github.com/jerairrest/codeception-lumen

Take a gander. I've also put in for a pull request but I haven't got a response from the original maintainer.

Cheers!

Jer

Comment: I did see this, the main guy who is looking after the repo is on leave today (USA holiday) so I will merge in your PR and see if I can build a sample app with at least a codeception test.  Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I'm having what I think is a namespace conflict, I've reverted to using PSR-0 for the module namespace instead of PSR-4 otherwise codeception can't find the module. I need to get composer updated to see if that works, stand by for updates.

Comment: I'm still not getting anywhere with getting a test case to run.  I have made a few more changes in my codeception-lumen repo, you may want to update your fork. I have also created a simple dummy sample app, check it out here:

https://github.com/incube8/codeception-lumen-sample

You will see a runtests.sh script there which you can use as a command line test runner.

Comment: OK the test case is working now. I have pulled in your changes, merged them onto the master branch, and updated the codeception-lumen-sample code to comment out the assert that was failing -- see at the github repo for more information. Thanks for your PRs, that was very useful.